# How to get the names of the objects/get (k, v) pair while iterating a list?

Tags: r, list, loops, iterator, iteration

Say I created a list and gave some names to the objects in the list.

```
list = rep(0, times = 20)
list = lapply(list, initialize_list)
names(list) = names
```

Now I want to iterate through all the objects in the list. I can perform any operation on the object, but I just can't find a way to get the name of the object at the same time. Is this possible to achieve in either a `for` loop or a `lapply` call without resorting to explicitly writing

```
for (name in names(myList)) {
    v = myList[[name]]
    ...
}
```

?

The existing answers don't seem to be exactly what I want, and I seemed to only find a relevant [blog post](http://www.statisticsblog.com/2010/03/r-tip-iterating-over-list/) which provided the above seemingly clumsy solution.

Comment: You could use `purrr::imap`, which is roughly equivalent to `Map(function(.x, .y){...}, .x = some_iterable, .y = names(some_iterable))` (or just use `Map`)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the index of the name.

```
lst = rep(0, times = 20)
lst = lapply(lst, sum)
names(lst) = letters[1:20]
for (id in seq_along(names(lst))) {
  v = names(lst)[id]
}
```